# Should @@ used in LaTeX3 for name spacing be the jobname?

Tags: latex3

The old timers in the LaTeX 3 Team must have been missing their `@@` when the l3doc name spacing convention for internal macros was introduced.

But at least now we have a reasonable name spacing scheme by convention that is a step nearer to encapsulation of package code. Personally I think this is one of the greatest ideas implemented in LaTeX 3.

Some languages such as Go namespace based on directories, e.g.,

```
package main

   import "fmt"
   import "golang-book/chapter11/math"

   func main() {
     xs := []float64{1,2,3,4}
     avg := math.Average(xs)
     fmt.Println(avg)
   }
```

Two small modifications in `l3docstrip` and `l3doc` make it easy to set the module name from the `\jobname`

```
     \edef\replaceModuleInLine{%
        \noexpand\replaceAllIn\noexpand\inLine{@@@@}{\string aa}%
        \noexpand\replaceAllIn\noexpand\inLine{__@@}{__\jobname}%
        \noexpand\replaceAllIn\noexpand\inLine{_@@}{__\jobname)%
        \noexpand\replaceAllIn\noexpand\inLine{!@@}{\jobname}%
        \noexpand\replaceAllIn\noexpand\inLine{@@}{__\jobname}%
        \noexpand\replaceAllIn\noexpand\inLine{\string aa}{@@}%
      }%
```

Similarly code in l3doc can be changed like:

```
     \tl_replace_all:Nnn #1 { _ _ @ @ } { _ _ \jobname }
```

The `!@@` construction is a hack to be able to say:

```
     !@@_do_something:n
```

and get:

```
     \modulename_do_something:n
```

for functions that one might want to export in a programming API (like for example the l3 `\keys_define:nn`).

In the actual package there will be no need for a guard `<@@=module>` but only for guards `<@@=>` where one might want to skip the name space.

The idea can easily be extended now that we have most of the tools to extend this to `\RequirePackage` and `\usepackage` if one wants to adopt a scheme similar to Golang's based on paths. This will also have the advantage that all packages in one directory like for example `l3draw` to name space all files with the same prefix.

Do you think this is a good idea? What can it break? How can it be improved?

Comment: This sounds more like a discussion but ...

Comment: ... aren't you assuming that the module name is linked to the file name? Have you seen for example `l3basics`?

Comment: @JosephWright Yes it has to be more like a discussion. I have read through l3basics and understand well how things work at present, but please see the Golang example above as to how the name spacing  is using the filename to namespace, but the path for loading, so you can have multiple `math.go` packages.

Comment: Also, the reason that `@@` doesn't apply to the public API is so that in the sources it's easy to spot 'internal' usage.

Comment: @JosephWright I am not assuming the current methods are linked to the filename, I am suggesting that if they do, it will be better for encapsulation. You can still have private and public API.

Comment: The file names contain numbers and so don't work in command names.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes but if we follow the Golang style they should be short and meaningful see https://blog.golang.org/package-names. If one insists in using numbers they can easily be replaced by roman numerals. In the extended version the name spacing is in reality the directory name.

Comment: "easily"? This will force lots of package name changes, which will break lots of other packages and documents. That would certainly not be easy.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Simple compile switches can leave exisiting packages untouched. Same one can change `\Require..` to `import`. It took me about an hour to do the change plus debugging on the first part. Probably one week's work to get the package loading mechanism defined. I am more worried about confusing kpathsea.

Comment: Well kpathsea is quite probably a problem too - packages must be found if there are in an arbitrary texmf tree *and* if there are in the current directory.